# Battery charge current

Tags: battery-charging

I set up my power source to 4.2 V @ 0.1 A. If I connect a Li-ion battery I get a current of about 0.1 A. If I connect a resistor of about 40 Ω I get a current of about 0.1 A. But if I put it all together (connect battery through the resistor) I get a current of about 10 mA.

In the first place I just wanted to calculate what resistor should I choose for a charging current of 0.1 A. But now I'm confused. Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: The charging current will be dependent on the state of charge of the battery (the voltage difference between the charger and the battery). Use Ohm's law: I = (Vcharge-Vbatt) / R. If the battery is nearly empty (around 3V), the current will be around 25mA and when it's nearly full it will be almost zero. *This is not a good way to charge Lithium Ion batteries. if you care for your battery and/or do not want to set fire to your house,  use a proper charging IC. There is a reason these exist.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charging current will be dependent on the state of charge of the battery (the voltage difference between the charger and the battery).

Use Ohm's law: I = (Vcharge-Vbatt) / R.

If the battery is nearly empty (around 3V), the current will be around 25mA and when it's nearly full it will be almost zero.

*Using just a resistor is not a good way to charge Lithium Ion batteries. There is no protection against overcharging or overdischarging.*

If you care for your battery and/or do not want to set fire to your house,  use a proper charging IC. There is a reason these exist.